# How does a LTC4162 powerpath battery controller start up? How to start it up on battery?

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, battery-charging

I'm using a battery controller IC ([the LTC4162](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC4162-L.pdf)) and this IC apparently is powered from the VOUT output based on its block diagram - which, if I understand correctly, is not connected to anything as long as neither of the powerpath FETs (VIN or VBAT) are driven:
[image]

I have tested this chip using the eval board and I lose communication with the chip as soon as I remove VIN but I've seen that's a normal feature to save battery by default.

[image]

Is the block diagram wrong? Otherwise, where and how does this chip get powered? I am concerned that, for example, VIN needs to be supplied first - in which case the chip would be able to see when the supply falls below the UV threshold and swap the powerpath; but that would mean I'd have to add some circuitry to make sure the chip starts up even with just the battery in (e.g. a DCDC from the battery to VIN that's switched on when VOUT is absent [depletion PMOS?]).

Answer (score 1):

> *Is the block diagram wrong? Otherwise, where and how does this chip
> get powered?*

Block diagrams that show absolutely everything are, in effect, circuit diagrams so, for it to be a block diagram, important information remains and less important (or mundane information) is or may be omitted. That's what block diagrams are all about.

So, look at the pins called CLN and CLP and imagine that CLN connects to Vout. Then imagine that a small value current limit resistor is fitted between CLN and CLP and that CLP connects to a MOSFET that acts as a current limit controller. The MOSFET, in turn connects to Vin. If the device goes into current limit then for sure, Vout is lost. But if there's a battery connected then there will be some internal linkage not shown in the block diagram but, if there's any doubt, the DS page 15 says this: -

> **Power Path Controller - The LTC4162 features input and output N-channel
> MOSFET charge pump gate drivers. These drivers make up a dual
> unidirectional power path system that allows power to be delivered to
> the system load by either the input supply or the battery, whichever
> is greater**.

And that reinforces what I was saying. On page 16 it also gives more details. Page 32 also gives useful information that tells you the chip won't cold-start without a battery being connected.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I understand, the device cannot regulate the input current, only reduce the charge current down to zero to meet the iin limit as best as it can. I understand that the chip is made so that either of the sources is connected, but my question is actually how it is accomplished starting from a state where VOUT=floating and both FETs are OFF. I still do not see how it is possible. You say that there is some internal linkage if a battery is connected and that might be what I am looking for. Care to expand on that? Thanks!

Comment: Without that linkage the device would not do what it says on the tin would it.

Comment: Sorry, that's exactly what's bothering me and led me to ask. Would you mind drawing what parts should be added to the block diagram such that it does? Because right now I'm really puzzled at the fact INTVCC comes out of VOUT. As much so for VIN as for VBAT in fact. As is, when either is connected, the chip's not powered and so cannot switch itself on to select the active powerpath. (+1 though)

Comment: I can't do that because I'd be guessing. The problem of losing Vin and the chip shutting down that you witnessed might be due to some setting you have incorrectly enabled maybe. I can only go on what it says in the data sheet.

Comment: Guessing is good :) Because at the moment I have no idea. The chip actually does not shut down when VIN is removed, I only lose comms. VOUT actually is, always, the greatest of the two sources. does the chip OR VIN and BATSENS+ for its own INTVCC supply - in addition to what is shown on the diagram?

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot make guesses like that. Maybe you have something incorrectly connected or maybe the chip is partially broken.